# Understanding the limits of definite integrals with infinity

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

While solving the integral
$$\int_2^\infty\frac{2}{t^2-1} \; dt,$$
I encountered one of the limits according to multiple sites is $i\pi$ and $\ln(3)$.  But in the final answer, only $\ln(3)$ is listed.  I am having trouble understanding how the limit  $i\pi$ is found. Thank you in advance

Comment: You're integrating a real function on the real line; you obviously can't get an imaginary answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, when finding the definite integral, the imaginary number can be disregarded?

Comment: Not really, I'm saying that it makes no sense in the first place. I have no idea where one would get $i\pi$ out of this.

Comment: I took the limit of -ln((1+x)/(1-x)) as it approached infinity and two.  By doing this it produced an imaginary limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{t^{2}-1}dt = -2\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}dt = -2\left[\tanh^{-1}\left(t\right)\right]_{2}^{\infty}
 $$
and
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\tanh^{-1}\left(t\right)=-\frac{1}{2}i\pi
 $$
and
$$-2\tanh^{-1}\left(2\right) = -\left(\log\left(3\right)-\log\left(-1\right)\right) = -\log\left(3\right)+i\pi
 $$
so
$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{t^{2}-1}dt = \log\left(3\right).
 $$

Comment: So we disregard  $i\pi$ as part of the solution?

Comment: @MarcD. The part $i\pi$ is deleted from the calculations.

Comment: @MarcD., isn't *disregarded*. $i\pi - (-\log(3) +i\pi) = \log(3)$.

Answer (score 11):

Why not to simply use partial fraction decomposition and write$$\int\frac{2}{t^2-1} \; dt=\int\Big(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}\Big)\,dt=\log\Big(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\Big)$$ which makes $$\int_2^\infty\frac{2}{t^2-1} \; dt=\log(1)-\log\left(\frac 13\right)=\log(3)$$